# Power BI Top N Bottom Too Many Results

Tags: powerbi, top-n

New to Power BI, obvs.

I've got too many results showing up in my Top N bottom 10 and would like to eliminate the items that are only single units to clean up the chart. So it looks neat like the Top N top donut.

I haven't found any other questions about this, so I suspect the answer is easy.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Top N top vs Top N bottom]

Comment: That means that all those categories have the same value. you will easily see that by turning that chart in a table. if the value is 0 you might consider filtering it out in the measure itself or using a filter on the chart

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto Thanks. I would like to filter out the categories with single units as there are no null values. Suggestions on the best way to do that?

Comment: What happens if you go to Units filter and set it up to only display values that are greater than 1?

Comment: @JustynaMK - Unfortunately that doesn't work. The units are aggregated by coupon - Description1 (the coupon name). I've been trying to edit the query to eliminate the singles, but I'm new to DAX.

Comment: @JustynaMK - I got your suggestion to work finally. I'm not sure why it's working now, but at least I can present it today. Thanks.

Comment: @ElainePowell sorry for the delay, I just looked at the forum. I'm glad you had it worked! Good luck.